# Pourquoi traduit-on « sportswashing » en employant la préposition « par » (...par le sport) alors que non avec « greenwashing » ?

Tags: anglais, prépositions, préfixes, mots-composés, morphologie

Je lis un [article](https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/golf/2022/06/10/sportswashing-explained-saudis-liv-golf/10003676002/) traitant de « [sportswashing](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sportswashing) », terme que Wikipédia et [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=SPORTSWASHING&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) traduisent par « blanchiment par le sport ». En comparant avec « [greenwashing](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwashing) », où l'on a « écoblanchiment », « [blanchiment vert](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8365406) » voire « mascarade écologique » etc., je me demande pourquoi on sent le besoin d'avoir recours à la prépostion *par* dans le contexte du sport plutôt qu'à l'adjectif *sportif*. Ensuite je me demande pourquoi on n'a pas tout simplement employé [*sport-*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sport-) comme élément formant en composition (« sport-blanchiment »).

Peut-on éclairer ma lanterne ?

Comment: J'aime bien *verchiement*...

Comment: @jlliagre —  Par le sport [ contemporain ] == Par [la *Phynance* qui s'intéresse à-] le sport ==  *Par des Structures corruptrices*, donc *Par le* [(ou, *Au) **moyen** du] sport*, moyen qui n'a rien à voir avec l'activité sportive elle-même et qui ne concerne pas les pratiquants/aficionados. *Le blanchiment sportif* serait entendu comme compétition entre “blanchisseurs” … pourquoi pas, le concept est déjà peut-être réalisé !

Answer (score 1):

*Green*, *eco(logical)* sont des adjectifs et *sport* un nom. En français, dans les composés nom-nom à trait d'union, le déterminant est le plus souvent le premier mot : plateau-repas, oiseau-mouche, compte-chèques, maître-chien, chou-fleur, etc.

"Sport-blanchiment" désignerait donc - sur le modèle de "sport-business", "sport-spectacle" - un sport qui se réduit à ou se caractérise principalement par du blanchiment. Cela n'a pas vraiment de sens, à part peut-être si on parle de blanchiment financier dans un circuit sportif entièrement dédié au recyclage de l'argent sale...

"Blanchiment sportif" est plus acceptable. Je dirais même que l'adjectif est plus justifié que dans le cas de *greenwashing* ou de *pinkwashing* puisqu'après tout, du sport est réellement pratiqué lorsqu'on fait du *sportswashing*. Il y a de vrais événements "sportifs" quelles que soient les intentions derrière.
L'expression reste tout de même plus ambigüe que "blanchiment par le sport".

Answer (score 0):

Parce qu'un néologisme comme "sport-blanchiment" donnerait envie à trop de gens de se crever les yeux. Et que "l'exercitatio-blanchiment" prêterait carrément à rire. Mais je pense que si le sportswashing était aussi en vogue que le greenwashing, les gens verraient de quoi tu parles en évoquant la "mascarade sportive" aussi sûrement qu'ils pigent ce que peut être la "mascarade écologique". Même sans que tu utilises "par".